# Richtextbox Max length

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several controls in my windows form, namely a Richtextbox and 10 buttons which represents a numpad (from 0-9). When a button is clicked, it will insert the corresponding number into the Richtextbox. I have set the MaxLength property to 6, however i seem to be able to insert more than 6 characters into the textbox by hitting on the buttons. My code is as follows:

```
private void num1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richtextbox.Text = richtextbox.Text.Insert(0, "1");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

> MSDN - Gets or sets the maximum number of characters **the user** can type or paste into the rich text box control.

So you need to check the length in your code.

#### Sample

```
private void num1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richtextbox.Text.Length >= 6)
        return;
    richtextbox.Text = richtextbox.Text.Insert(0, "1");
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - RichTextBox.MaxLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.maxlength.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I have another problem now though. I have set my num2ButtonClick to "richtextbox.Text = richtextbox.Text.Insert(1, "2");" but when i try to hit num2Button I get an error.

Comment: ArguementOutofRangeException was unhandled
Specified arguement was out of range of valid values.
Parameter name: startIndex

Comment: I think it's trying to insert "2" into index 1 but since it doesn't exist, hence the error? How can i fix this?

Comment: No, you cant insert on position 1 (first argument) if the box is empty

Comment: If i hit on num1Button and num2Button it inserts the values 1 and 2 into the textbox normally. But if i try a num2Button, the error above appears.

Comment: Hmm so how can i fix so that it will insert the value after the previous character (or empty) in the textbox?

Comment: I don't understand why you need this.

Comment: Oh, i'm trying to simulate a PIN device

Comment: But why you need insert ? Why not doing `richtextbox.Text += <PressedKey>;` to append the key to your box ?

Answer (score 0):

MaxLength works only if enter threw keyboard into textbox. You can change the text of more than the MaxLength using code behind.

Hence you will have to double check this condition while changing the text

```
private void num1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(richtextbox.Text.Lenght < 6)
        richtextbox.Text = richtextbox.Text.Insert(0, "1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MaxLength refers to the maximum length a user can *type* into the box. It does not mean the maximum text length a developer can set. You will need to check the current length of the string before inserting more characters.